# Can someone distinguish which of these verbs is a participial adjective and explain?

Tags: participial-phrases, nonfinite-verbs, deverbal-adjectives

The boy deeply engaged in a conversation had brown hair.

The boy deeply engaged in a conversation.

Comment: Welcome to ELU--consider English Language Learners as a site for your question.  You need to show research you did and why you still have a question if you want an answer here.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a good website on it.

http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-adjectives.html

Upon further reading I believe both use a participial adjective. "engaged" is the key word as said by the website.

Engaged is a participial adjective. It is a past participial. And deeply modified it. 
I hope I could help somewhat.

Comment: This is not really a complete answer. Can you add an explanation of how this applies to the specific sentence in the original post?